# I am getting a "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type" when calling my function

Tags: c++

In this program, I am supposed to call `animal.at(0)->makeSound()` in `main()` and have it return `"Woof"` from the public member function `makeSound()` for `Dog`. However, when I compile the code as written, it gives me an error:

> base operand of '->' has non-pointer type

While I know there are other ways around this, I am not allowed to modify any of this code except for the `vector` type and the element list of the `vector`, as this is a practice problem from an old homework I got wrong.

If somebody could tell me how to set up the array properly (`vector <MISSING_TYPE> animal {MISSING VECTOR ELEMENT};`) so that it will compile, you will be saving me for finals. What I have now is currently incorrect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual void makeSound() {  
    cout << "Animal!" << endl;
  }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  void makeSound() {
    cout << "Woof" << endl;
  }
};
 
  
int main()
{
  Dog dog;
    
  vector<Animal> animal {dog};
  animal.at(0)->makeSound();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: animal.at(0) is of type Animal, not Animal*.  So you just use a `.` not an `->`

Comment: `->` is the dereference access oprator. Since `animal` contains objects, not pointers to objects `->` is ill formed. Use `.` instead

Comment: `vector<Animal>` is not a vector of pointers. `animal.at(0).makeSound();` is a correct call. I am pretty sure if you read the error message carefully, the compiler suggests you using the period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is because the `vector` is holding `Animal` objects, not `Animal*` pointers to objects, so you would have to use the `.` operator instead of the `->` operator to access the `makeSound()` member, eg:

```
animal.at(0).makeSound();

// or, since you KNOW there is 1 object in the vector, the
// bounds checking of at() is redundant, use operator[] instead:
//
// animal[0].makeSound();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/R0Qgg3)

However, although that will fix the compiler error, calling `makeSound()` at runtime will print `"Animal!"` instead of `"Woof"`, because you are not actually storing a `Dog` object in the `vector`, you are storing an `Animal` object due to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/).  To fix that, you would need to instead store an `Animal*` pointer to the `Dog` object, eg:

```
int main()
{
  Dog dog;
    
  vector<Animal*> animal {&dog};
  animal.at(0)->makeSound();
  // or: animal[0]->makeSound();
  
  return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DDHXPy)

Answer (score 0):

`animal.at(0)` is of type `Animal`, not `Animal*`. So you just use a `.` not an `->`

If you made animal a `vector<Animal*>` then you'd use `->`

Comment: that still won't work in this case, though, due to object slicing.

Comment: I fixed it by making it vector<Animal*> animal {&dog}; Thank you!